# VBA Double vs Single rounding

Tags: vba, math, excel

in my MS Excel I have different behavior of rounding operations for different data types:

In case of Single:

```
? Application.Round(6.575!, 2)
 6.57
```

In case of Double:

```
? Application.Round(6.575#, 2)
 6.58
```

Does anybody know why?

---

**UPDATE**: [@paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) gave an excellent answer, so just to reproduce it shortly in here:

In Single precision, 6.575 is 0 10000001 101001 0011 0011 0011 0011 in binary representation, or 6.57499980926513671875. And this rounds to 6.57

In Double precision more 0011 are added and their weight is enough to make the number slightly greater tham 6.575 (6.57500000000000017763568394003), and hence it rounds to 6.58

Comment: (+1 - much more interesting than your previous rounding question :))

Comment: We all can sometimes be stupid, no one's perfect

Comment: I like to be stupid several times every day - hence my hundreds of questions on this site.

Comment: By the way, see my update on the topic. In the situation when computer presents numbers like this, my DoRound subroutine from previous rounding question might make perfect sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Probably* because of the different limits of floating point precision. When you use a value like `6.575`, the computer chooses the closest approximation. For a single, this may be:

```
6.574999993
```

which will round down. For a double, it may be:

```
6.57500000000001
```

which will round up.

---

Clarifying, IEE754 single precision bit-value for 6.575 is:

```
s eeeeeeee ffffff ffff ffff ffff ffff f
0 10000001 101001 0011 0011 0011 0011 0
```

(that repeating `0011` at the end is usually the sign of an infinitely recurring value, one not exactly representable).

The double is also very similar, it has the bits:

```
s eeeeeeeeeee ffffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ...
0 10000000001 101001 0011 0011 0011 0011 ...
```

which also has the repeating sequence (see below).

[image]
The reason it cannot be represented exactly is because you can only do that is the number can be constructed by summing powers of two (like 4, 2, 1/16 and so  on) within the number of bits allowed for.

Generally, you cannot always trust what gets printed out since the print routines know about and adjust for the limited precision. So you'll almost certainly get 6.575 since that's the closest decimal value to the given bit pattern, but the bit pattern itself will be used for calculations.

Comment: Maybe! I wonder how to check if you're right. I tried to print more digits of this number using ? Format(6.575#, "0.0000000000000000") but it didn't help, I got only 6.5750000000000000. The only interesting test I managed to do was adding to Watch the following expression 6.575! + 0#. It gave me Double with value 6.57499980926514. It *seems* to contradict to your statements. Or it confirms them?

Comment: @Gus, you've used a single 6.575! and coerced it to a double, to see it end up at 6.57499... That matches with your described behaviour of singles being rounded down.

Comment: @mehow, well, vba is programming (and ieee754 formats definitely are, given the half-billion questions here on SO about it), it's not like OP was looking for a cell formula :-)

Comment: @Gus, it's one I wrote after seeing Harald Schmidt's excellent online version (which is unfortunately single precision only and I needed double as well). See http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/.