# VBA debugger precision

Tags: c++, vba, excel, vbe

I had a `single` which I believe the C++ equivalent is `float` in VBA in an Excel workbook module.  Anyways, the value I originally assigned (876.34497) is rounded off to 876.345 in the Immediate Window, and Watch, and hover tooltip when I set a breakpoint on the VBA.  However, if I pass this `Single` to a C++ DLL C++ reports it as the original value 876.34497.

So, is it actually stored in memory as the original value? Is this some limitation of the debugger?  Unsure what is going on here.  Makes it difficult to test if what I'm passing is what I'm getting on the C++ side.

[image]

I tried:

```
?CStr(test)
876.345
?CDbl(test)
 876.344970703125 
?CSng(test)
 876.345
```

VBA isn't very straightforward, so at some level it must be stored as 876.34497 in memory.  Otherwise, I don't think `CDbl` would be correct like it is.

Comment: Surely that's just a formatting choice of the UI?

Comment: The short answer is declare as Double instead. You say CDbl is returning the correct value, but it's not. This SO post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18504731

Answer (score 1):

VBA variables of type "single" are stored as "32-bit hardware implementation of IEEE 754[-]1985 [sic]." [see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324.aspx].

What this means in English is, "single" precision numbers are converted to binary then truncated to fit in a 4 byte (32-bit) sequence.  The exact process is very well described in Wikipedia under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format .  The upshot is that all single precision numbers are expressed as

```
(1) a 23 bit "fraction" between 0 and 1, *times*
(2) an 8-bit exponent which represents a multiplier between 2^(-127) and 2^128, *times*
(3) one more bit for positive or negative.
```

The process of converting numbers to binary and back causes two types of rounding errors:

(1) Significant Digits -- as you have noticed, there is a limit on significant digits.  A 22 bit integer can only have 8,388,607 unique values. Stated another way, no number can be expressed with greater than +/- 0.000012% precision.  Reaching back to high school science, you may recall that that is another way of saying you cannot count on more than six significant digits (well, decimal digits, at least ... of course you have 22 significant binary digits).  So any representation of a number with more than six significant digits will get rounded off.  However, it won't get rounded off to the nearest decimal digit ... it will get rounded off to the nearest binary digit.  This often causes some unexpected results (like yours).

(2) Binary conversion -- The other type of error is even more pernicious.  There are some numbers with significantly less than six (decimal) digits that will get rounded off.  For example, 1/5 in decimal is 0.2000000.  It never gets "rounded off."  But the same number in binary is 0.00110011001100110011.... repeating forever. (That sequence is equivalent to 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/16*(1/8+1/16) + 1/256*(1/8+1/16) ... )  If you used an arbitrary number of binary digits to represent 0.20, then converted it back to decimal, you will NEVER get exactly 0.20.  For example, if you used eight bits, you would have 0.00110011 in binary which is:

```
  0.12500000
  0.06250000
  0.00781250
+ 0.00390625
------------
  0.19921875
```

No matter how many binary digits you use, you will never get exactly 0.20, because 0.20 cannot be expressed as the sum of powers of two.

That in a nutshell explains what's going on.  When you assign 876.34497 to "test," it gets converted internally to:

```
1 10001000 0110110001011000010011
     136       5,969,427
```

Which is (+1) * 2^(136-127) * (5,969,427)/(2^23)

Excel is automatically truncating the display of your single-precision number to show only six significant digits, because it knows that the seventh digit might be wrong.  I can't tell you what the number is exactly because my excel doesn't display enough significant digits!  But you get the point.

When you coerce the value into double precision, it uses the entire binary string and then adds another 4 bytes worth of zeroes to the end.  It now allows you to display twice as many significant figures because it is double precision, but as you can see, the conversion from 8 decimal digits to 23 binary digits and then appending another long string of zeros has introduced some errors.  Not really errors, if you understand what it's doing; just artifacts.  After all, it's doing exactly what you told it to do ... you just didn't know what you were telling it to do!