# Excel VBA Single VS Double Data Type

Tags: excel, vba

I thought this was a simple question but I'm having such a hard time finding an answer:

I understand that the Single and Double data types store floating point numbers. But I don't understand the maximum digits they can represent?

For example, if I use the Single data type in this simple macro:

```
Sub Float()
    Dim Result As Single
    Result = 10 / 3
    MsgBox Result
End Sub
```

The result is 3.333333

There's 7 digits. But when you look at the range that Single can accommodate - it indicates that it can hold way more digits.

Same thing with the Double type. I change the variable to Double, then the result is 3.33333333333333 (15 digits) but Double can hold way more digits?

I'm confused.

Comment: Precision is limited to 15 significant figures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precision is limited to 15 significant figures max. And  other answer mentions 7 for Single.

If you instead print to the sheet you will see the following:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As Single
    Dim s2 As Double
    s = 10 / 3
    s2 = 10 / 3
    [A1] = "Single"
    [B1] = s
    [A2] = "Double"
    [B2] = s2
    [B1:B2].NumberFormat = "0.000000000000000000"
End Sub
```

[image: Data]

Regarding your later question as to the decision on precision; there is an international standard governing this.

[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

> The IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754) is a
>   technical standard for floating-point computation established in 1985
>   by the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers (IEEE). The
>   standard addressed many problems found in the diverse floating point
>   implementations that made them difficult to use reliably and portably.
>   Many hardware floating point units now use the IEEE 754 standard.

Someone may correct me on this but I believe this to be the prevailing standard.

For you comment re Single precision wiki has a good explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

You can access the standard [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4610935/?part=1).

Comment: I think I need to re-word my question. So if Single can store numeric values ranging from –3.402823e38 to -1.401298E-45 for negative values and 1.401298E-45 to 3.402823e38 for positive values - these numbers have way more than 7 digits -> if it stores a number with that many digits - why only 7 digits of accuracy? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format  AND https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: Thanks QHarr - I'm going to have to dig into that and see if I can figure it out. I wish there was a layman's explanation for this!

Comment: Is this now answered?

Comment: Hi QHarr, yes I figured it out (methinks). Thanks for checking up! I'll indicate that this post has been answered. :)

Comment: It is in part that there is agreement internationally on precision so you don't get varied results across systems etc. It is to allow for comparison. Apples with apples.

Answer (score 4):

singles store data in 4 bytes, they allow 7 digits of accuracy.
doubles store data in 8 bytes, they allow 15 digits of accuracy.

This answer [VBA Double vs Single rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504637/vba-double-vs-single-rounding) might explain better.

Comment: Better technical explanation +1

Comment: I think I need to re-word my question. So if Single can store numeric values ranging from –3.402823e38 to -1.401298E-45 for negative values and 1.401298E-45 to 3.402823e38 for positive values - these numbers have way more than 7 digits -> if it stores a number with that many digits - why only 7 digits of accuracy? This is what I don't understand.

Comment: Accuracy and precision are not the same.

Comment: Please see latest answer I posted - I hope I'm getting it? lol

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent article online that explains floating point excellently:

https://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/

From what I am able to understand so far:

My confusion stemmed from the fact that I did not understand that there is a difference between how many digits is stored for the data type VERSUS how many digits can be accurately calculated and returned by the data type. Is this correct?

For example: The Single data type requires 4 bytes (32 bits) of storage space. 24 bits are allotted to the significand (with sign) and 8 bits for the exponent.
Calculations with values of Single data type will always return 7 significant digits because that is the level of precision that can be promised?

I hope I am understanding this correctly...