# Issue copying number from one xlsm to another via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to reset some cells in an xlsm and then copy a single cell from one workbook to another via a VBA macro. Code is below:

```
Range("E19").Copy
Range("E6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("E5").Value = 0
Range("E8:E9").Value = 0
Range("E11:E12").Value = 0
Range("E25:E28").Value = 0
Range("E30").Value = 0
Range("I25:I31").Value = 0
Range("G2").Clear

Dim ubbPrevDay As Single
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
'open the workbook with data
Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("<file path censored for privacy>")
ubbPrevDay = objWorkbook.Worksheets("UBB").Range("C13")
'close the workbook
objWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Range("E4") = ubbPrevDay

Dim name As String
name = InputBox("Enter your name")
Range("G2").Value = name
```

The operation runs and copies a value, but occasionally copies the decimal just a little bit incorrectly. Today it copied '550687.88' as '550687.875'. I verified that the data on the workbook being copied is correct so something is getting altered in the macro process. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

-Kevin

Comment: Are you 100% sure the value wasn't 550687.875 and was showing as 550687.88 as a result of the no of decimal points being displayed?

Comment: Change the decimal place on the source file and you will likely see it expand. There is no reason for the value to change when simply using copy/paste. Also, if the value you are trying to move is `ubbPrevDay` then use `ubbPrevDay as Double` as this will expand the allotted memory by a factor of 2. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023795/excel-vba-single-vs-double-data-type/52023847) is worth a read if curious to see why you would want to use `Double` over `Signel`

Comment: @norie I am 100% that's not the issue as I typed 550687.88 in that file earlier in the day and nobody else touched it.

Comment: @urdearboy I will try Double but I doubt that's the cause, it's definitely worth a try.