# VBA, why can I see Double type return result (12 digits) for a Single function like Timer?

Tags: vba, function

I would especially like to thank Tim for his comment, since I apparently did not use the right key words to locate the answer, and this makes it look like I did not do enough of my own research. Thanks to Tim, my question was answered indirectly in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023795/excel-vba-single-vs-double-data-type/52023847) and its cookie crumb followup links.  I am responding with a high level answer since my lay persons perspective may be useful and sufficient for other persons with the same level of training and experience.

It now clear that MS documentation statement that the max number for single is "3.4028235E+38 for positive values" is ***not*** mathematically accurate. Per Wikipedia the correct value is less than this, it is exactly 3.4028234664E+38.

One least significant digit lower, i.e. 3.4028234663E+38,  does NOT exist in the CPU world. I think the second highest number is something like 3.4028234nnnE+38. A "casual" user such as myself reading MS info would not see the impact of the fact that the base ten versions of numbers do not exist inside a CPU, it is binary representations. This has significant impact on representations of number to various binary precision levels. Of course most casual users know that PCs use zeros and ones, but I did not grasp the impact on base ten equivalents of this without further learning. I was thinking in terms of single precision having 7-8 actual digits in base ten, which is not true.  There are more digits, it is just that the precision is of the order of 7-8 base 10 digits.  One would think after 5 decades of using programing as a tool for my profession (experimental physicist) I would already know this, but it is only now that I came across an issue that these details impact my project.

I would appreciate constructive criticism if I have any significant errors in my own answer.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

MS documentation [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function) VBA Timer is returns a [Single](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/single-data-type) data type so max of 8 digits plus exponent. The correct answer from Wikipeia is  3.4028234664 × 10*38

Indeed, if I insert a code line to debug print Timer directly (debug.print Timer), I see a 7 digit number. I am guessing only 7 digits vs max of 8 for Single is just chance because of the time of day this was...since the most significant digit at this time of day is >3 cant be the max of 8 digits.

HOWEVER, if I assign Timer to a Double data type and print it, it can show up to 12 digits.

I can even assign the Timer result to a Single data type variable (which prints out as 7 digits), convert that data type variable to a Double type variable and get 12 digits printed.

***So how can I see Double digit type results for a Single function?***

BTW on my machine, a Timer call takes about 60 nSec, so with Timer only being updated ever few milliseconds, chances are all Timer calls will return the same value as seen in this example.

Test Code Output:

- Timer Direct Print: 72851.07
- Timer Direct Print as Double 72851.0703125
- Timer Single: 72851.07
- Timer CDbl(Single): 72851.0703125
- Timer Double:72851.0703125

Test Code:

```
Sub TimerDigits()
Dim sSeconds As Single, dSeconds As Double
sSeconds = Timer
dSeconds = Timer
Debug.Print "Timer Direct Print:"; Timer
Debug.Print "Timer Direct Print as Double"; CDbl(Timer)
Debug.Print "Timer Single:"; sSeconds
Debug.Print "Timer CDbl(Single):"; CDbl(sSeconds)
Debug.Print "Timer Double:"; dSeconds & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023795/excel-vba-single-vs-double-data-type/52023847

Comment: @Tim I am a little unsure, maybe you can explain. Why is it that [vba] has so many duplicate questions, that are not closed as, well duplicates?

Comment: @TomBrunberg - I couldn't say.  I'm mostly here, so I don't really know how it compares to other tags.