# (10*1.11=11.1) evaluates as FALSE. How to correct it

Tags: excel, vba

(10*1.11=11.1) evaluates as FALSE.

```
a = 10
b = 1.11
c = 11.1
' (mathematically: 10*1.11=11.1)
debug.print a*b = c
```

I get False (incorrect) rather than True (correct).
I know this happens because of the binary way of counting and therefore I have to live with it.

What is the best way to make it work correctly?
Is the following the best solution when comparing numbers with decimals? Is it reliable?

```
round(a*b,2) = round(c,2)
```

Comment: That or precision as displayed, which is possibly rather drastic.

Comment: Defining a,b and c as `single` evaluates to true

Comment: ?1.11+1.11+1.11+1.11+1.11+1.11+1.11 = 7.77
False

Comment: Whereas Double is false https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504637/vba-double-vs-single-rounding

Comment: Also, `Debug.Print CDec(a * b) = CDec(c)` is true

Comment: @SJR: as far I can see even with Single there are imprecisions in decimal conversion so I could have problems when comparing decimal numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point arithmetics is almost never correct, when `.1` is involved. The reason is that `.1` cannot be represented as a `1/2^n` within 16 digits of `n`.

These are a few numbers, with which there would not exist problems in floating point, because they can be represented as `1/2^n`:

- 0.125 =  1/2^3
- 0.5 = 1/2^1
- 0.375 = 1/2^2 + 1/2^3

Thus, the [type decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/decimal-data-type) comes to solve the problem. This is the best way:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim a, b, c 'declaring as Variant, as Decimal cannot be declared in VBA

    a = CDec(10)
    b = CDec(1.11)
    c = CDec(11.1)
    Debug.Print a * b = c

End Sub
```

Comment: Does that approach solve all such rounding problems?

Comment: @SJR - Yes. This is the silver bullet, being used in all financial software. It comes with a price, though. Decimal is a bit slower than double.

Comment: Nice one. I wonder why MS doesn't mention it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result

Comment: @SJR - I don't know. Still, their [floating-point numeric types documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) of C# is quite good.

Comment: Thanks @Vityata! Very useful answer.   According to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary, a Decimal is 14 bytes large but if you click on "Decimal" it says that it's 12 bytes large. What's the truth?

Comment: 1.11*7=7.77 is FALSE.   cdec(1.11*7)=7.77 is TRUE.  1.11*7=cdec(7.77) is TRUE.  cdec(1.11*7)=cdec(7.77) is TRUE.    Do you know why is the cdec on just one side sufficient?

Comment: @6diegodiego9 Read again. The documentation you see when you click on Decimal shows three different bits of information being stored.  The 12 byte refers only to the unsigned integer part of the data.