# Can VBA code modify cell contents after input?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like  VBA code that will multiply the contents of a cell by the contents of a different cell when I enter an input.

For example, I have 75% in cell B1.  When I enter 25,000 in cell C1, I want the 25,00 to be automatically multiplied by the 75% in B1 so the cell shows 18,750. What is the simplest code that will do this?  I'm not a coder, but was using an event modifier and range -- and it did work once!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("C1:F1")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = Target.Value * Range("B1").Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

I got it to run the first time, but it owuld run continuously as I use the spreadsheet.

Comment: A much better use of Excel, according to me, is to use a new column and use a standard formula in it (= C1*B1)...

Comment: @B.Go - this will not work, if you want to enter the value in C1 and see the result in C1.

Comment: I meant that in D1, indeed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Should look something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C1:F1"))'range of interest

    'any cells affected?
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'loop over affected cells
        For each c in rng.cells
            c.Value = c.Value * Me.Range("B1").Value
        Next c
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your logic:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:F1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = Target.Value * Range("B1").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a few checks, before starting the real code. The checks are the following:

`If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` - disable the code when 2 cells are added in the same time. Quite useful, when multiple cells are deleted.

`If Not IsNumeric(Target.Cells(1)) Then Exit Sub` - make sure that the value, which is entered is numeric

`If Not IsNumeric(Range("B1")) Then Exit Sub` - make sure that the value, which is multiplied by is numeric.

Additionally, it is a good idea to define the `multiplier` as a decimal, just to avoid some floating point problems, that may arise ([(10*1.11=11.1) evaluates as FALSE. How to correct it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449141/101-11-11-1-evaluates-as-false-how-to-correct-it/58449605#58449605)).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(Target.Cells(1)) Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsNumeric(Range("B1")) Then Exit Sub

    Dim multiplier As Variant
    multiplier = CDec(Range("B1"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:F1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = Target.Value * multiplier
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```