# vba incorrectly entering cell values from single variable

Tags: excel, vba, variable-types

I have the task of entering the weight of every product onto our company's system (over 65,000), so am using Excel and a slightly limited knowledge of vba to automate that where possible.

The plan is, I input part of a product name and then the figure to be entered, and it enters that figure in all the relevant rows on the sheet.

The problem; the number I enter is seldom more than 2 decimal places, however the figure entered on the sheet is not the same - always very nearly there, but not quite. For example when I just tried to enter 0.88 in relevant cells, it entered 0.87999995.

Code (simplified):

```
Sub EnterWeight()

Dim Filter As String
Dim Weight As Single

Filter = InputBox("Add text filter", "Add Filter")

w = InputBox("Insert weight in Kg", "Enter Weight", 1) 
'(yes, I know it should be 'mass in Kg', but ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ )

Weight = CDec(w)

Debug.Print Weight 'To test that it's the correct number, always seems to be ok.

    For b = 1 To Activesheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(b, ) Like "*" & Filter & "*" Then 'Find the filter in any part of the cell

            If Cells(b, 2) <> "" And Cells(b, 2).Value <> SG Then 'Cells already populated with a different value

            y = MsgBox("Product """ & Cells(b, 1).Value & _
                """ already has a weight assigned of " & _
                Cells(b, 2).Value & Chr(13) & _
                "OverWrite?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, _
                "Weight already assigned")
                If y = vbYes Then Cells(b, 2).Value = Weight

            Else
                Cells(b, 2).Value = Weight
            End If

        End If

    Next
End sub
```

Can anyone tell me why that wouldn't enter the `Weight` variable correctly in the relevant cells? hunting through google doesn't seem to have produced an answer, although perhaps I'm just asking the wrong thing.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Change the `.NumberFormat` of the cell? Side note - why are you `CDec`ing here and why is `weight` a `Single`? Personally would just roll with `Double` the whole way through.

Comment: And use `Application.InputBox` instead of `InputBox` too.

Comment: Thanks ... umm, ```Cdec``` was something I vainly tried in case it fixed the problem, turns out it hasn't actually done anything. It's not the format of the cell I'm bothered about (makes no difference to me how it looks), but it affects calculations that are happening with that cell later on. As to the Single/Double debate - no reason, I just know that 'Double' was made for extra accurate things and I didn't need that kind of accuracy.

Comment: would you mind explaining what difference ```application.inputbox``` would make?

Comment: You can specify the `Type` of the input.

Comment: Well, apparently you *do* need that kind of accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue can be minimised down to:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim Weight As Single
    Weight  = InputBox("Insert weight in Kg", "Enter Weight", 1)
    Cells(2, 2).Value = Weight
End Sub
```

Entering ".88" into the input box causes the cell to receive "0.879999995231628"

**However, changing the `Weight` to `Double`**:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Weight As Double
    Weight  = InputBox("Insert weight in Kg", "Enter Weight", 1)
    Cells(2, 2).Value = Weight
End Sub
```

Entering ".88" into the input box causes the cell to receive "0.88"

---

Check out the answer to [VBA Double vs Single rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504637) for a very detailed explanation of why this happens.